# 3rd monitor suddenly ceases to operate

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, dvi

A couple months ago I purchased an active mini-displayport to DVI adapter to plug a 3rd monitor I had laying around into my computer. The adapter only supports resolutions of up to 1080P but this isnt a problem to me duy to my monitor being less than that (I forget the resolution, however it is a 4:3 monitor... The resolution it shows in the screenshot below is not accurate). It worked perfectly since I bought it until I just turned on my rig recently (It was working earlier today as well). When I did turn it on just recently as mentioned, The 3rd monitor (Leftmost in configuration on my desk) did not respond to my computer being turned on. Usually, my leftmost and middle monitor would show my BIOS and startup stuff, and the rightmost monitor stays black until im at my log on screen, when the leftmost monitor (the one with the problems) displays my log on screen.

Essentially what I have going is a 4:3 monitor set as my furthest left monitor, plugged into my GPU with Mini-Display Port. My middle monitor is a 16:10 as well as my rightmost monitor, both of which are plugged into the GPU through DVI. To clarify, the lefrmost one is the one with the problem.

Catalyst Control Centre refuses completely to even consider the possibility of there being a 3rd monitor attached to my GPU, however the display control pannel will accept that the monitor is there, but won't let me enable it, or even as much as give me a monitor identity. When I try to enable it, the control pannel says it's "unable to save settings."

[image: Heres what my system tells me. Monitor 3 is actually on the most left of my desk instead of the most right as shown here.]

Anyone know what's happening here? I don't get it. The cables and connections from GPU to Monitor are fine as far as I can tell. I've had some problems with this GPU in the past as well; [Random GPU output glitches, possible dying GPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/654261/random-gpu-output-glitches-possible-dying-gpu)

Could the above link provide any insight to my problems? As I asked there, should I invest in a new GPU?

**EDIT:** I started up my computer late today and everything functioned as usual. The system did in fact display on all 3 of my monitors and everything is the same as it was before. The only thing that mildly confused/bothered me was that all of the shortcuts on my desktop were offsetted- Rather, that top-leftmost icons on my desktop were shifted down, pushing the other icons into the next vertical icon row on my desktop. No Problem, really, just strange.

I still want to know why this was occuring, as so I can diagnose it in the future if it occurs again.